# Can't upload files to Google Drive once I connect to Google Colab

Tags: google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

When I want to work on Google Colab, I usually first upload data and python code to a folder in my Google Drive. Then I double-click on the notebook file and it opens in Colab where I can mount the drive as:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
```

Now if I want to upload more files to my Google Drive, it stops not responding (in Google Chrome) and doesn't let me upload the files. If I unmount the drive as:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.flush_and_unmount()
```

or even terminate the Colab session, I still find it hard to upload files to my Google Drive. Can anyone please guide what I am doing right?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

- try to terminate the run time and try again
- this might be some other issue, not an issue with the google colab, this will not block the uploads in any case. I ran google colab very hard GPU computation and at the same time, I have uploaded some files to drive during the open session. I successfully uploaded it.
- try to do the clear cache and hard reload